# Reading a file from Databrick filesystem

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I used the following code to read a shapefile from dbfs:

```
geopandas.read_file("file:/databricks/folderName/fileName.shp")
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to do so and I get the following error

```
DriverError: dbfs:/databricks/folderName/fileName.shp: Permission denied
```

Any idea how to grant the access? File exist there (I have a permission to save a file there using dbutils, also - I can read a file from there using spark, but I have no idea how to read a file using pyspark).

After adding those lines:

```
dbutils.fs.cp("/databricks/folderName/fileName.shp", "file:/tmp/fileName.shp", recurse = True)
geopandas.read_file("/tmp/fileName.shp")
```

...from suggestion below I get another error.

```
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonSecurityException: Path &#39;file:/tmp/fileName.shp&#39; uses an untrusted filesystem &#39;org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem&#39;, but your administrator has configured Spark to only allow trusted filesystems: (com.databricks.s3a.S3AFileSystem, shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.SecureAzureBlobFileSystem, shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.SecureAzureBlobFileSystem, com.databricks.adl.AdlFileSystem, shaded.databricks.V2_1_4.com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem, shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem, shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem)
```

Comment: Run dbutils commands to check if the file really exists .. ex: dbutils.fs.ls("/databricks/folderName/")

Comment: Fortunatelly, it does exists, that's why I'm so surprised. I can save a file there but I can't read it :(

Answer (score 2):

GeoPandas doesn't know anything about DBFS - it's working with the local files.  So you either need:

- to use the DBFS Fuse to read file from DBFS (but there are some [limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations)):

```
geopandas.read_file("/dbfs/databricks/folderName/fileName.shp")
```

- or use [dbutils.fs.cp command](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#file-system-utility-dbutilsfs) to copy file from DBFS to the local filesystem, and read from it:

```
dbutils.fs.cp("/databricks/folderName/fileName.shp", "file:/tmp/fileName.shp", recurse = True)
geopandas.read_file("/tmp/fileName.shp")
```

P.S. But if the file is already copied to the driver node, then you just need to remove `file:` from the name.

Updated after updated question:

There are limitations on what could be done on the AAD passthrough clusters, so your administrator needs to change cluster configuration as it's described in the [documentation on troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#--troubleshooting) if you want to copy file from DBFS to local file system.

But the `/dbfs` way should work for passthrough clusters as well, although it should be at least DBR 7.3 ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#--limitations))

Comment: It sounds great, but now I have another problem (untrusted connection) I included in the first post. Could you help me with it as well?

Comment: what is the link?

Comment: I updated the opening post in this topic and added error message there :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, the answer is easier than I could thought:

```
geopandas.read_file("/dbfs/databricks/folderName")
```

(folder name as it is a folder with all shape files)

Why it should be like that? Easy. Enable the possibility of checking files on DBFS in admin control panel ('Advanced' tab), click on the file you need and you will get two possible paths to the file. One is dedicated to Spark API and another one for File API (this is what I needed).

:)